# How to view all the services running on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How would I be able to view all the services running on aws. I have been charged some $$$, so what to close the services that are running. Most of the $ are being charged for KMS(Key Management System). When I go inside the KMS from aws console there's nothing.

Please Help!!!!

Comment: In the AWS management console, you can go to the Billing Dashboard and click **Bill Details**. Costs are listed by service and then by Region (eg "US West (Oregon)"). If you go to the KMS console for that region, you can see if any resources are still in place. Can you edit your question to show what you were charged for?

Answer (score 43):

Depending on the access level you have in the project, there are 2 options

**Option 1 (Mentioned in the previous comments)**

- Go to my Billing dashboard
- Under left pane -> Billing -> go to Bills.

This option work only if you have access to the billing information

**Option 2 - Use the VPC Dashboard**

- Search for VPC

  [image]
- In the VPC Dashboard you can see "Resources by Region"

  [image]

**Notes:** This will give you information about the selected region in the top right corner, however, each resource contains The see all regions dropdown that gives an indication of where that resource is used.

Comment: vpc way to view active services is neat!

Comment: Along with the per-region VPC viewer, they also now have the "EC2 Global View" page which shows total services per-region... but alas, it's only EC2 services so hiding anything else AWS might be charging you for. Classic Amazon move, how anyone puts up with their dishonest shitshow is beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 27):

Give this a try:-

1. Go to **my Billing dashboard.**
2. Under **left pane ->  Billing -> go to Bills.**
3. `Here you can find bills according to month with charges based on different services.`
4. `If you click on a specific service(drop down), you can find, under which region the service has been launched and its charges`

Comment: This is the best answer. The bill shows all the services and cost per service (mostly zero) and allows you to expand services that are not zero and see which region they're in.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkStouffer. Glad that it is helping the community

Answer (score 18):

Another option to see all resources being used is to go to the "AWS Resource Groups"-->"Tag Editor".
Select "All Regions" and "All Supported Resource Types" (or any specific resource you are interested in. Click "Search resources". (hopefully) Done!
[image]

Comment: This should be one of top answers in stackoverflow

Answer (score 7):

Often the [Cost Explorer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-what-is.html) is one of the best tools to identify where the money is being spent without much delays -- if you check on your bill, it will take the entire cycle to find out.

On the top of your chart on CE, you can change the grouping and usually [Usage Type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-filtering.html) makes it easier to understand the exact usage of that service.

Also, keep in mind if you don't see the expected service on AWS Console, double-check if you are looking at the correct region (top right of your screen).

Comment: CE is one of the only useful tools, no wonder AWS makes it so difficult to find... and as usual, there is no universal cost analysis region-wide. My client had a relational database billing him almost $500/mo for a basic WordPress site that he wasn't even aware of because it was buried so deep in their system.

Answer (score 5):

## Use AWS Resource Explorer

I found AWS Resource Explorer the best place to see all the services running and resources allocated. It **allows to filter by type and by region**.

The only issue is it may take some time to finish indexing all the resources. It also shows a few extra records for resource explorer service itself, but this is more of a feature than an issue.

https://resource-explorer.console.aws.amazon.com/

[image]

Comment: This is how to do it!

Comment: does it also cost money? lol

Comment: @oldboy it might. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resource-explorer/latest/userguide/welcome.html#pricing-resource-explorer




"Use AWS Resource Manager on free instances without incurring charges. Normal AWS rates are applied for applications that require more resources than the default environment provides."

https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%23always-free&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all&awsm.page-all-free-tier=5

Comment: "on free instances" -- wonder what this means. does it mean on any free-tier service (and if you incur any charges by exceeding the limit, youll also incur charges for resource manager)?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, go to **Billing Dashboard**. It open as "AWS Billing Dashboard" (notice  `../billing/home` in the url).

1. If you want to view all different aws-services you have been consuming, along with their bills. From the left-pan menu, navigate to => **[Cost Explorer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/ce-what-is.html) -> Launch Cost Explorer**.
   *Here you can find bills according to your months, regions, service-type, usage-type, etc. with charges based on different services.*
2. If you want to view your cumulative bill (regarding all usage of aws services), from the left-pane menu go to **Bills**.

Answer (score 3):

`Top right corner user menu > billing dashboard (from drop-down)> bills (left sidebar menu)`

This is exactly what I found in my case and find that two unnecessary ec2 instance is running in unwanted region that I'm paying extra.

And a little thought. AWS is only telling me what I'm charged for. That amount is `already transferred to AWS`. Instead if it would have shown me a nicer dashboard that says all the services currently running. Then I could find out which one I don't need anymore and prevent that unwanted loss of money.

Comment: this seems to be the way

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can check aws bills to see for what you have been charted for - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/view-aws-payments/; Also, aws has a tool called trusted advisor that will be able to help you to optimize your pricing. Lastly,  there is a tool called cost explorer - https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/, but personally I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login into AWS Console
2. Click on EC2 Global View

[image]

3. You can see the all active services and resource consumption by all regions
   [image]