# Disabled activated service in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I started learning AWS 2 months ago - free versin with my verified card. After that i started with new projects in other technologies so i didn't have time to continue with learning. Today i get emailed that i have 85% usage of free services - so they warned me.

```
AWS Free Tier Usage as of 11/27/2020    AWS Free Tier Usage Limit
639.0 Hrs   750 hours per month of Amazon EC2 Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region
```

i got this type of warning. The problem is when i logged in with my account, i can't find some EC2 running. I checked through all regions and there everywhere in the field - Instanes ( running ) on each region is writed 0. So where is my instance running that maked whole time increasing usage of the free hours ?

Or it is not ec2 it is something else ? I didn't learned a lot of for AWS so i need help here to prevent extra paying in future.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63895443/13126651 follow this, this tells you the way how to see which services are being used month wise and region wise.

Comment: Please note that the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is a billing discount. It is not a "free version" of AWS. You can view your usage of the Free Tier via the [Top AWS Free Tier services table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/tracking-free-tier-usage.html#free-tier-table).