# AWS Free Tier Usage Limit and delete EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

I received aws billing email notification that "exceeded 85% of the usage limit for one or more AWS Free Tier-eligible services". When I check EC2 instance are running zero?

Can someone explain where to check running instances and if there is no any running instances why I received email?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check other regions.

Comment: Here in this post, I have answered  on how to view all the running services in AWS, it also tells under which region services are running https://stackoverflow.com/a/63895443/13126651