# Why my AWS have too many public snapshots?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-billing

I am getting small amount of bill on AWS, even I m on free tier, I got billing on RDS. I reviewed my RDS but found no instance, as I deleted it earlier. I found a snapshot which I deleted. After couple of days I reviewed my billing and still found increment. I went through the RDS dashboard and in public snapshot tab, **I found 223 snapshots which I did not created. I also found snapshot that were create on 2014, and at that time my account didn't exist.** I do not know should I delete all 223 snapshots or are those some system related stuff. [image] [image]

Comment: Yes. It is clear now that I am  not charging for public snapshots

Comment: Glad it helped, If it helped you do accept it/upvote it so that it helps others in the future

Comment: Please upvote the question as well, so that it helps other as well for best suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public snapshots is a way to share snapshot with other aws account publicly.

According to [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ShareSnapshot.html#USER_ShareSnapshot.Public)

> You aren't billed for the backup storage of public snapshots owned by other accounts. You're billed only for snapshots that you own but If you copy a public snapshot, you own the copy. You're billed for the backup storage of your snapshot copy. If you create a DB instance from a public snapshot, you're billed for that DB instance.

**Note**: You can delete only the public snapshots that you own. To delete a shared or public snapshot, make sure to log into the AWS account that owns the snapshot.

To pinpoint which service is causing those extra dollars check out this answer -> [How to view all the services running on AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63895443/174777)